# Approximate cloning of a qubit, given multiple starting copies

Tags: quantum-information, approximations

Suppose I'm given several clones of a qubit in a pure unentangled state. That is to say, I'm given the state $(a \left|0\right\rangle + b \left|1\right\rangle)^{\otimes n}$. My goal is to make $d$ clones of the qubit; to expand the input state so that it approximates the target state $(a \left|0\right\rangle + b \left|1\right\rangle)^{\otimes n+d}$.

This can't be done exactly because of the No Cloning theorem. On the other hand, if $n$ is very large, then we can use tomography to get a pretty good approximation of $a$ and $b$. Once we have that, we can start churning out as many copies as we want.

**I'm looking for papers/websites/answers giving bounds and on how accurately and efficiently this can be done, as well as explicit techniques for doing it and how well they perform.**

---

For example, suppose we know that $a$ and $b$ are constrained such that $a = \sin \theta$, $b = \cos \theta$, and $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$. Then a very simple $n$-to-$n+d$ cloning procedure is to count the given qubits that are ON in the computational basis and estimate $\theta$ from that (note that we're conditioning operations on the count, not measuring the count). So, given $\psi(t) = (\cos t) \left|0\right\rangle + (\sin t) \left|1\right\rangle$, we get something like:

$\psi_{\text{target}} = \psi(\theta)^{\otimes n+d} = \sum_{l=0}^{n+d} \left| n+d \atop l \right\rangle \cdot \cos^{n+d-l} \theta \cdot \sin^l \theta$

$\psi_{\text{made}} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \left| n \atop k \right\rangle (\cos^{n-k} \theta) \cdot (\sin^k \theta) \cdot \psi(f_n(k))^{\otimes d}$

$\psi_{\text{target}}^* \cdot \psi_{\text{made}} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \left( n \atop k \right) \cdot (\cos^{2n-2k} \theta) \cdot (\sin^{2k} \theta)  (\cos^d \left( \theta - f_n(k) \right))$

Which, for $n=d=10$ gives this plot w.r.t. $\theta$:

[image: plot of parallel-ness]

Since the inner product stays above 0.8, the resulting state is basically at most ~35 degrees off of the true state (which is pretty good in a $2^{20}$-dimensional complex vector space).

But presumably there are processes that perform better than this, and without restricting the state space as much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[R.F. Werner, Optimal Cloning of Pure States](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9804001) describes the optimal procedure for cloning multiple copies of the same *pure* state (which, remarkably, for pure states is independent of the figure of merit).

> Abstract: We construct the unique optimal quantum device for turning
>   a finite number of $d$-level quantum systems in the same unknown pure
>   state $\sigma$ into $M$ systems of the same kind, in an approximation of the
>   $M$-fold tensor product of the state $\sigma$.