# Understanding the optimal approximate qubit cloning method

Tags: quantum-information, density-operator

I'm trying to understand the operation used for optimal cloning of pure qubits states from the paper [Optimal Cloning of Pure States by R. F. Werner](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9804001v1.pdf).

The paper describes the optimal cloning method $\widehat{T}$, which approximates the state $\sigma^{\otimes n+d}$ when given the state $\rho = \sigma^{\otimes n}$. $\sigma$ is promised to be a pure 2-level state. The optimal method is: tensor $d$ randomized qubits onto the state, project the system onto the symmetric subspace for $n+d$ qubits, and normalize. Symbolically:

$$\widehat{T}(\rho) = \frac{n+1}{n+d+1} s_{n+d} \cdot (\rho \otimes (I_2 / 2)^{\otimes d}) \cdot s_{n+d}$$

*I don't understand what projecting onto the symmetric subspace means, exactly*. If I was implementing this method on a quantum computer, or performing an experiment, how do I actually achieve the projection? And how do I compute its effects on paper?

**What I've tried**

The paper doesn't give a definition of $s_m$ more concrete than "a projection for the symmetric subspace". But I think this is the correct expression:

$$s_n = \sum_k^n \widehat{\left| n \atop k \right\rangle} \widehat{\left\langle n \atop k \right|}$$

Where $\widehat{\left| n \atop k \right\rangle}$ is a unit vector made up of a uniform superposition of all the classical states with exactly $k$ qubits on (out of $n$ total qubits). More specifically:

$$\widehat{\left| n \atop k \right\rangle} = {n \choose k}^{-1/2} \left| n \atop k \right\rangle$$

$$\left| n \atop k \right\rangle =
\left\{ \begin{align}
k = 0 & \rightarrow & \left| 0 \right\rangle^{\otimes n} \\
k = n & \rightarrow & \left| 1 \right\rangle^{\otimes n} \\
\text{else } & \rightarrow & \left| n-1 \atop k-1 \right\rangle \left| 1 \right\rangle + \left| n-1 \atop k \right\rangle \left| 0 \right\rangle
\end{align}\right\}$$

I figured that the cloning method should work just as well on any symmetric state, so I picked a very simple one to analyze: $\left| 0 \right\rangle^{\otimes n}$.

However, when I simplify $s_{n+d} ((\left|0\right\rangle \left\langle 0 \right|)^{\otimes n} \otimes I_{2^d}/2^d) s_{n+d}$ I get the result $\frac{1}{2^d} \sum_k^d \widehat{\left| n+d \atop k \right\rangle} \widehat{\left\langle n+d \atop k \right|} {d \choose k}$. Which only has a $\frac{1}{2^d}$ chance of being in the correct state. Which is further from $\left| 0 \right\rangle^{\otimes n+d}$, in terms of trace distance or overlap, than reported by the paper. And I end up not needing the normalization factor.

Clearly I'm making a mistake somewhere. Thus why I'm asking:

**What precisely is meant by "project onto the symmetric subspace"? How would it be realized in practice? How do I compute the result on paper?**

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from the discussion below, you are interested in the overlap between the cloned state and the perfect clone.

The cloned state is obtained as
$$
\tau=\Pi(\sigma^{\otimes d}\otimes (I/2)^{\otimes n-d})\Pi\ ,
$$
where $\Pi$ is the projection onto the symmetric subspace, and you are interested in the overlap with 
$$
\gamma =\sigma^{\otimes n}\ .
$$
This overlap is given by
$$
\mathrm{tr}(\gamma\sigma) = \mathrm{tr}(\sigma^{\otimes n}\Pi(\sigma^{\otimes d}\otimes (I/2)^{\otimes n-d})\Pi)\ .
$$
Now using cyclicity of the trace, you can apply the projection as well to $\gamma$, which already lives in the symmetric subspace.  Thus, we have that
$$
\mathrm{tr}(\gamma\sigma) = \mathrm{tr}(\sigma^{\otimes n}(\sigma^{\otimes d}\otimes (I/2)^{\otimes n-d}))\ .
$$
For a pure state $\sigma$, this evaluates to $(1/2)^{n-d}$.

Comment: I don't think that's the right answer. The paper says that the overlap factor should be $\frac{N}{N+2} \frac{M+2}{M}$, where $N$ is the given number of copies and $M$ is the desired total number of copies at the end. Also, a [naive cloning method I tried](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/229505/approximate-cloning-of-a-qubit-given-multiple-starting-copies) scales better than that (as you may recall).

Comment: I think the point is that the cloning is not simply adding maximally mixed states and projecting on the symmetric subspace.  It is a CP map which has the same outcome as that procedure, but with optimal success probability.  But I'll have to check more carefully.